# How to change default path in File Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-10, path

On Windows 7 I can right-click the File Explorer icon, choose Properties, and change the Destination.

On Windows 10 this seems impossible:

[image]

How can I change the default folder when opening File Explorer? I want for example `explore D:\MySounds\`

EDIT: Sean screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new **shortcut**.

1. **Right-click** where you want to have it (i.e. Desktop)
2. **New** -> **Shortcut**
3. `Type the location of the item` would be **D:\MySounds**
4. Click **next** and give a **Shortcut name**
5. Press **Finish**

Change the Icon by opening the **Shortcut Properties**, **Tab Shortcut** and click on **Change Icon**

Either search now for the Windows Explorer icon, or enter into the `Look for Icons in this file:` **explorer.exe**, hit enter and there you have the explorer icon...

**edit**
If you want to change that icon[image]

**Shift + Right-click** on it (in your taskbar), choose **Properties** and change it's target to **D:\MySounds**
[image]

Comment: This "adds" a new link. I want to use Explorer icon.

Comment: So what? Change the Icon and remove the old shortcut...
Btw... Downranking instantly because you can't follow the most simple steps is a really bad behaviour...

Comment: If I remove it, once I open a new folder, it automatically open that icon (so, twice icons). I want only 1 icon that manage folders.

Comment: I think I don't really understand what you need :-)
If you create a new shortcut (i.e. on your Desktop), you can remove the old one, whereever it is. If you've got it in your quick launch bar on your Taskbar, remove it from there and drag your newly created shortcut into that. Now when you click that icon your Explorer will open with your path (D:\Mysounds) and you will only have 1 icon.

Comment: I have added some more information into my answer. If thats still not what you are looking for, you have to explain your needs further.

Comment: The File Explorer icon is a icon that will "open" for every folder you open. I just need to go to a default path when I click on it. I don't want to create additional link/icon on taskbar. Just only ONE File explorer icon, with a default path.

Comment: That's the problem: I can't change "Target" path in Windows 10. I can on Windows 7, not on 10! Its grayed... (see my screenshot on the topic)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late answer. I had the same problem and found a trick in the following link. As the author mentioned, this may not be the correct way. Anyway, it works for me.

http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-make-windows-10s-file-explorer-start-any-location-you-want

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score -1):

Open `File Explorer > View > Options > General.` From there, you can set the `'Open File Explorer To'` field.

Comment: Uhm? I've only two fields, not a customizable one: http://oi58.tinypic.com/es1cfm.jpg

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't display correctly on the link you've provided.

Comment: Ok. I've added it to the main question...

Comment: But on Windows 10 there are only two options: *"Quick access"* and *"This PC"*

Answer (score -1):

1. On the Taskbar right-click the existing *File Explorer* icon and click **Unpin this program from the taskbar**
   [image]
2. Create a new (temporary) shortcut on the Desktop
   [image]
3. Specify the target of the shortcut as follows:
   [image]

   - To open a special folder (e.g. My Computer) by default, use the correct [CLSID namespace](http://www.mydigitallife.info/command-line-switches-to-display-special-objects-or-folders-when-opening-windows-explorer/) of the object in the following format:
     `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /E,::<CLSID>`

     For example, the syntax to open *My Computer* is:
     `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /E,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}`
   - To open a standard path by default, use the format: <sup>*[source](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-change-windows-explorer-default-folder/)*</sup>
     `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /n, /e, <folderpath>`
4. Name the shortcut **File Explorer** then click **Finish**
   [image]
5. Right-click the shortcut and choose **Pin to Taskbar**
   [image]
6. Delete the temporary shortcut from the Desktop
   [image]

---

Here's the syntax to open some common special folders. A complete list can be found at [mydigitallife.info](http://www.mydigitallife.info/command-line-switches-to-display-special-objects-or-folders-when-opening-windows-explorer/):

**My Computer**
`%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /E,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}`

**My Documents**
`%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /N,::{450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}`

**Recycle Bin**
`%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /N,::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}`

**Default Web Browser or Navigator (IE, Firefox, Safari, Google Chrome)**
`%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /N,::{871C5380-42A0-1069-A2EA-08002B30309D}`

**Control Panel**
`%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /N,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}`

Comment: It doesn't works! Every time I click on the folder pinned in the Taskbar, it opens a new Icon on the task bar. So not inside the same pin/icon. That's my problem...